# How to use Ruby DBI's 'select_all' vs 'execute-fetch/each-finish'

Tags: ruby, dbi

Here is my sample code for using DBI:

```
dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:host=#{server};database=mysql", user, pass)
rows = dbh.select_all("SHOW TABLES")
```

The rows printed look like:

```
[["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"],
 ["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"], ["user"],
 ["user"]]
```

This is printing the last table in a MySQL database, but the total number of records  is proper.

If I do this using execute-fetch/each-finish sequence, something like:

```
sth = dbh.execute("SHOW TABLES")
sth.each do |row|
  rows << row[0]
end
sth.finish
```

It gives me proper results like:

```
["columns_priv", "db", "func", "help_category", "help_keyword", "help_relation",
 "help_topic", "host", "proc", "procs_priv", "tables_priv", "time_zone", "time_z
one_leap_second", "time_zone_name", "time_zone_transition", "time_zone_transitio
n_type", "user"]
```

Comment: I've encountered this too. I've logged it as a bug on RubyForge http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29513&group_id=234&atid=967

Answer (score 2):

The same is also happenning when I query an MS SQL DB using `DBI.connect("DBI:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};...")`

My work around was to forcably convert the DBI::Row to an array:

```
sth = dbh.execute "..."
begin
  return sth.map{ |row| row.to_a }
ensure
  sth.finish
end
```

I'll bet $1,000 that the issue is to do with buffer reuse - a possible 'performance' enhancement that has had underirable side effects!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `dbh.select_all` returns an instance of Enumerator, which yields the same row on each iteration. See this pseudocode to understand what I mean:

```
def select_all(query)
  db_row = Row.new
  reader = @connection.execute_reader(query)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    until reader.end?
      db_row.populate_from(reader)
      yielder.yield db_row
      reader.next!
    end
  end
end
```

Thus, if you're using select_all without block, an Enumerator will be returned, which basically yields the same db_row object.

This is just a guess, but, I believe the truth is nearby.

---

The [source code](https://github.com/erikh/ruby-dbi/blob/master/lib/dbi/handles/statement.rb)  `fetch` method definition says that I was wrong, because `@row` is `dup`licated on each iteration. Well, probably the error is somewhere up the stack.

Comment: Someone (probably inside the MySQL DBD or low level driver) is re-using a buffer. If you `dbh.select_all("SHOW TABLES").map { |r| [r.object_id, r.first.object_id] }` you'll see the first ID changing but not the second one.