# Ruby database connection returning same records multiple times

Tags: ruby, oracle, dbi

I inherited a Ruby script that is connecting to the database successfully and counting the number of rows:

```
componentid = 5
components=conn.select_all("select * from component_details where componentid=?", componentid)
puts components.count.to_s + " total components   #outputs correct number of components
```

```
components.each do |component|
  puts component["ORGID"].to_s      #outputs same ORGID from first record in the database
end
```

returns

```
123
123
```

However when running it in my Ruby script, it is only returning the first row two times.  When run directly from the Oracle database:

```
select * from component_details where componentid='5';    # returns 2 distinct rows

ID  | ORGID  | COMPONENTID
1   | 123    |  5
2   | 456    |  5
```

I am not sure why is it not looping through each row and displaying the correct ID for each record and only displaying the ID for the first record two times (in the above example).  I do not have the ability to update version and/or database gems at this time.

```
Version:  ruby 1.9.3
Ruby DBI:  OCI8
```

Comment: how does `select * from component_details where componentid=?` work directly? have you defined `?` somewhere?

Comment: sorry, i updated the original thread with what was running from oracle sql.  the ? was a placeholder for the componenetid of 5

Comment: Please don't add a summary of the solution to your question. Instead, upvote answers that help and select the answer that was the solution. SO isn't a message board or forum, it's more like an online reference book of Q&A, with separation between questions and answers. "[ask]" and its linked pages help explain.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in "[Ruby DBI select_all vs execute-fetch/each-finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972379/ruby-dbi-select-all-vs-execute-fetch-each-finish) ".

`select_all` apparently reuses the buffer and has unforeseen consequences, so I switched to `execute` instead.